# Spfx extension : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of undefined

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-extensions, applicationcustomizers

I am trying to change Save button name to Submit using below code but it does not work sometimes if I do load page twice below script throw error.

My Script having JS is added in my Site Assets library and below is code in application customizer to load JS.

Code in extension:

```
 const head: any = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement;
    
 let articleRedirectScriptTag: HTMLScriptElement = document.createElement("script");
 let jsurl = `${this.context.pageContext.web.serverRelativeUrl}/SiteAssets/MyScript.js`;
 articleRedirectScriptTag.src = jsurl;
 articleRedirectScriptTag.type = "text/javascript";
 head.insertAdjacentElement("beforeEnd", articleRedirectScriptTag);
    
 console.log('jsurl:',jsurl);
```

Code `in MyScript.js`:

```
what();
function what(){
     document.getElementsByClassName("ms-Button--primary")[0].innerText="Submit"
};
```

Comment: Where is the save button? Is this a button in SharePoint list form or any other button on SP page? There might be better selector for this.

Comment: this is in Newfrom.aspx page in Modern UI

Comment: Try inspecting element and add the screenshot to your question

Comment: You can use this: `document.querySelector("button[role='menuitem'][title='Save']")` to select the Save button from top of the form (Menu/Command bar in form).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
function what(){
    let buttonElement = document.getElementsByClassName("ms-Button--primary")[0];
    if (buttonElement) {
        buttonElement.innerText = "Submit";
    }
};
```

There maybe a better selector we can use for accessing the button element from DOM. Please "Inspect" the button element and add screenshot to your question. I will suggest you the better selector is possible.

**Edit**:

As per my test on modern experience:

You can use below selector to select the "Save" button at the bottom/end of the form:

```
document.querySelector("button[data-automationid='ReactClientFormSaveButton'][class^='ms-Button']")
```

Use below selector to select the "Save" button from top of the form (Menu/Command bar in form):

```
document.querySelector("button[role='menuitem'][title='Save']")
```

Comment: its work but if i do refresh page second time it show old value

Comment: Try hard refresh (Ctrl + F5) once. Maybe it is browser caching/cookies issue.